# How to solve these issues while integrating with facebook

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

[image]I'm implementing facebook login integration but facing this issues
I tried with live hash key and debug hash key.but still showing this package
name is not available in play store

[image]

Comment: 1 : Copy your Android app details in Notepad and remove your Android App from facebook developer console. 2: Now make app live 3: now add your Android app back to console

Comment: Post it as an answer! @AD10

Comment: @Rahul Chandrabhan - why ?

Comment: Comment should be used to clear things. Your comment is in many points so its better you put it as an answer @AD10

Comment: I'm confused please help me out to this issues.i'm stuck here

Answer (score 1):

Till the time you did not upload your application to Google Play Store, you will get this message. This is the message which says that you facebook-api will not available to your application publicly and you will not be able to login using facebook.

Until you do not upload your application at Google Play, You can make some users as developer or testers so they will be able to test login-via-facebook. See how to add [test-users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users/)

Comment: After add user to tester and developer.will work probably?

Comment: @SumitKumawat Yes all features will work for those users who will be added into the list.

Comment: please see edited question.1 more screenshot attached there

Comment: @SumitKumawat Thats what I was saying.. you will get this error for those users who are not in list of test users or dev. Try with account which is added as test user.

Comment: @SumitKumawat See at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users/ to add test users